# how to set z-index of dialog box higher than you tube video using jquery?

Tags: jquery-ui, youtube

I'm providing an interface where user can integrate You tube videos in their web pages. I could integrate the video, but to provide edit property function, I tried to add a Span with text "Edit Properties" . But, I could not make it to display over the you tube object. Also, the dialog boxes (Jquery Dialog) also are displayed behind the you tube control. How can I make the dialog boxes to overlap the you tub object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `wmode` to transparent. `<param name=wmode value=transparent>` for `object` and `<embed wmode=transparent>`